# rvest read_html could not read the url

Tags: r, web-scraping, rvest

I have this simple code to do webs craping

```
url <- "https://www.ville-ideale.fr/paris-10e 
         arrondissement_75110.php#commentaires"
web <- read_html(url)
```

The problem is that I receive this error:

[image]
id it a problem with the link? Because I tried the same method with other links and it works normally. 
PS: I tried the same method with that link this morning and it didn't show any error

Comment: https://www.ville-ideale.fr/infosite.php sure looks like it prohibits this type of activity

Answer (score 1):

I am able to run below code without any glitch

```
library(rvest)
url <- "https://www.ville-ideale.fr/paris-10e%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20arrondissement_75110.php#commentaires"
web <- read_html(url)
```

Comment: Don't forget to let us know if it solved your problem by marking it as the correct answer :)

Comment: Yes sure! :) Still can't resolve the problem but what I discovered is that the link can be read only 7 or 8 times after that I get the same error. I have a list of 20 links to read so what I am doing now is: read 8 by 8 and restart my R session each time. I don't have an explanation for that but it works that way!

Comment: like  @hrbrmstr  said. the web site is blocking that because it seems that I don't have the right to use the data without permission

Comment: Oh, I see. You are right... it seems to be a copyright issue.